# Add batch variable to groovy email-ext pipeline

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Not a pro on groovy or batch, but here goes.

I have a groovy script where a small part of it sends email when something fails in jenkins pipleine. Here is the catch code which sends email if something goes wrong.

```
catch (Exception e){
    def buildNumber = env.BUILD_NUMBER
    def buildurl = env.BUILD_URL        
    def buildjobname = env.JOB_NAME

    bat 'for /f "delims=" %%a in (user_id.txt) do set USER_ID=%%a'

    emailext body: "Failure in build number $buildNumber for the job name $buildjobname. See URL for more detail: $buildurl",
    subject: "Failure in build number $buildNumber for the job name $buildjobname",
    to: 
}
```

As you can see I have a line which does some bat shell script where it stores the user_id content into the USER_ID variable by reading a file. Now I want to use the USER_ID variable in my `to` attribute (something like this: `to: USER_ID`) but it seems this is not the way to do it.

What am I misisng

Edit: I guess I have to use EnvInject plugin?

Answer (score 1):

In a Jenkins pipelines code, you could use bat output to get your userId as a variable. Example :

```
catch (Exception e){
    def buildNumber = env.BUILD_NUMBER
    def buildurl = env.BUILD_URL        
    def buildjobname = env.JOB_NAME

    def userId = bat script: 'for /f "delims=" %%a in (user_id.txt) do echo %%a', returnStdout: true

    emailext body: "Failure in build number $buildNumber for the job name $buildjobname. See URL for more detail: $buildurl",
    subject: "Failure in build number $buildNumber for the job name $buildjobname",
    to: "${userId}"
}
```

I'm not so sure about how to output your userId using bat script (more familiar with shell script, sorry) but you get the idea...

Comment: I tried it out, got this error: `class hudson.plugins.emailext.EmailExtStep.setTo() expects class java.lang.String but received class java.lang.Integer`

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly, try with `"${userId}"` instead of `userId`, that will get you a String.

Comment: Writing `"${userId}"` gives me 0@domain.com and `'${userId}'` gives me ${userId}@domain.com.

Comment: `"${userId}"` is basically writing a string with variable substitution enable, it means that it will replace your variable userid with its value, hence the `0` displayed. `'${userId}'` is writing a string **without** variable substitution, this is not what you want. But provided code is correct, if you're not happy with the `0` displayed, you should check why your file has this `userId` and not the one you want... but this is not related to this issue !

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by using the a jenkins plugin

```
readFile 'user_id.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

in groovy, you could acces environment variables like the following:

```
groovy -e "println System.env.LOGNAME"
```

so it might be possible (if USER_ID is an environment variable) that you could access the content of the variable like

```
to: System.env.USER_ID
```

but maybe in your jenkins env, the variable is already present?

```
to: env.USER_ID
```

?

Another possibility could be:

```
to: new File("user_id.txt").text.replace("\n", "")
```

Comment: Nope there is no such thing as `env.USER_ID` but there is `env.USERNAME` but does not give user id of who started the build.

Comment: maybe not directly in the map after "to:". You could try to create a variable with **def userId = new File("user_id.txt").text.replace("\n", "")** and use the variable in the **to: userId** ...

Comment: Hmm seems like I am not able to use it? I get this error `Scripts not permitted to use new java.io.File java.lang.String`

Comment: Thats sad. I'm currently know nothing about jenkins... :-(

Comment: Thanks for the help though. I am looking if inject environment variable might help